# Matching dataframes according to the order of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes containing information as follows:

```
> df1:
  X1      X2
Adele    Soul
Cher     Pop
Sting    Rock
Beyonce  R&B
```

and

```
> df2:
name    completeName
 B        Beyonce
 A        Adele
 S        Sting
 M        Madonna
 E        Elvis
 C        Cher
 D        Duffy
```

And I am trying to match them to create new column in `df1` to make it look like this:

```
> df1:
 X1       X2     Name
Adele    Soul     A
Cher     Pop      C
Sting    Rock     S
Beyonce  R&B      B
```

I have tried with `df1 <- df1[order(match(df2$name, df1)), 1]` but somehow I cannot get the `Name` column in the same order as `df1$X1`.

Any ideas? Preferably in `Base R`.

I have been applying ideas from other similar question but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You are matching against the data.frame 'df1' instead of a column in 'df1'.  Try with `merge` i.e. `merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'X1', by.y = 'completeName', all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: It works but the result is not respecting the order of the columns in `df1`.

Comment: It looks like a join operation.  Try with `merge` or one of the join functions.  Please check the dupe link